# Bundle Node Typescript project into one executable js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

How can I bundle an entire TypeScript project into one single executable js file

for example `node app.js` where `app.js` would be the compiled project.

I've tried playing around with the `compilerOption` `outFile` without success. I couldn't get an executable out of it.

Comment: `gulp` can help you, especially `concat` to join files.

Comment: I tried concat today but my issue with it is that it makes a mess of my dependency

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://medium.com/isovera/3-ways-to-implement-typescript-into-your-project-39a2c9d7f850) quite useful. Personally I prefer tsc.

I'm attaching the tsconfig.json file I use as a reference (I guess yours might be different).

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "./dist/server",
        "strict": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types", "./typings"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "dist",
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/) with [webpack-node-externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals).

Webpack is primarily meant to bundle browser code, which means it'll try to embed your code's dependencies. Using webpack-node-externals prevents that, and still gives you all of webpack's nice features (optimization, trnspilation with loaders, etc.).